# How can I make a Custom Listbox on Symbian 3rd OS?

Tags: listbox, symbian

I want to make a custom listbox on Symbian 3rd OS.

I need it can set 2 or more line information and have a Icon in the right of every item.

And the listbox can scorll.

Did anyone make a custom listbox ? I need a sample to learn how to do it.

Thanks for your help, Friend~

Answer (score 2):

I think that should help you:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/List_box_example

Comment: Thanks, But I mean I need a custom listbox can fit my requirement as the question said. Not the listbox from sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start making completely new user interfaces then check out Qt. There you have more freedom on screen design.

Are you working on your schoolwork or why can't you use one of the stock listboxes?